# execute python script using docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a problem with docker. I have a docker image

[docker images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z21JB.png)

and I want to execute a simple python script on the kakadadroid/python27-talib image. The script is located in /home/Elise/technical_indicator.py.

but when I try:

```
docker run --volume=$(pwd):/workspace kakadadroid/python27-talib:latest python home/Elise/technical_indicator
```

I have the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'home/Elise/technical_indicator.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me. I'm not an expert in docker.

Kind regards

Emmanuel

Comment: Please post your docker file.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your command line `docker run --volume=$(pwd):/workspace kakadadroid/python27-talib:latest python home/Elise/technical_indicator` it could have many causes. Try the following:

1. Your file path it's not correct. It should be `/home/Elise/technical_indicator.py` instead of `home/Elise/technical_indicator.py`. You've forgotten the `/` at the start of path specification.
2. The volume does not exist.

If the volume exists, the solution would be:

`docker run --volume=$(pwd):/workspace kakadadroid/python27-talib:latest python /home/Elise/technical_indicator`

Note: You should add your Dockerfile to let us understand better your problem.

Regards :)